# Where condition on linked table Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause

I am trying to create a search engine for my web app and I need it to select the results based on a condition applied to a linked table. I have a Posts table

```
title | content | user_id | date | rating | views |
```

the user_id column is linked to the users table

```
id | username | city
```

So when the user searches for posts in their city I want to somehow look at the post's author and their city. Something like this

```
Post::where('title', 'like', $title)->where('users.[Author's id]', $city)->get()
```

This is just an example. I don't know if this is at all possible. I am using Laravel 5.4.

There might be similar questions as this one, I am not sure but I will be grateful if you give a link to one of them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: it's that simple??

Comment: Yup, pretty much!

Comment: I just tested it and it worked, however, it's not the thing I was looking for. I am not going to select posts from a single user, but from multiple users that live in the same city as the searched one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing in the city, you just need to query the relationship with `whereHas`

```
Post::where('title', 'like', $title)->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($city) {
     $query->where('city', $city);
})->get();
```

This will search for all posts where the title is like `$title`, and has any users with the city of `$city`.